# Turbocharge a lambda function comparing values in two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got an OHLCV financial dataset I'm working with that's approx 1.5M rows. It's for a single security back to 2000 at a 1min resolution. The dataset had all the zero volume timestamps removed so has gaps in the trading day which I don't want for my purposes.

Raw data (df1) looks like:

Timestamp, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume

To fill in the all the zero volume timestamps I created an empty trading calendar (df2) using (`pandas_market_calendars` which is an amazing time saver) and I've then used `df3 = merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Timestamp', direction = nearest)` to fill all the timestamps. This is the behaviour I wanted for the price data (OHLC) but not for volume. I need all the 'filled' timestamps to show zero volume so I figured a lambda function would suit (as below) to check if each timestamp was in the original dataframe (df1) or not.

```
tss = df1.Timestamp.to_numpy()
df2['Adj_Volume'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x['Volume'] if x['Timestamp'] in tss else 0, axis=1)
```

I ran this for an hour, then two hours, then five hours and it's still not finished. To try and work out what's going on, I then used tqdm (progress_apply) and it estimates that it'll take 100 hours to complete! I running the conda dist of Jupyter Notebooks on an 2014 MacbookAir (1.7Ghz, 8Gb RAM) which isn't a supercomputer but 100 hours seems whacky.

If I cut down tss and df3 to a single year (~50k rows), it'll run in ~5mins. However, this doesn't scale linearly to the full dataset. 100 hours vs 100 mins (5mins x 20 years (2000 - 2019)). Slicing the dataframe up into years in a python level loop to then join them again afterwards feels clunky, but I can't think of another way.

Is there a smarter way to do this which takes advantage of vectorised operations that can be run on the entire dataset in a single operation?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try with `np.where`function and `.isin` method ?

```
import numpy as np
df2['Volume'] = np.where(df2['Timestamp'].isin(tss),df2['Volume'], 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the 120,720 times improvement in speed (5 secs vs 100 hours).